# Find all integer values for $m$ such that $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

We have $(m+1)x^2-(2m+1)x-2m=0$ where $m\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{-1\right\}$. We need to find all integer values for $m$ such that both roots of the equation are integers.

Here is all my steps:

- $x_{1,2}=\frac{(2m+1)\pm\sqrt{12m^2+12m+1}}{2(m+1)}\in\mathbb{Z}$

  $\Rightarrow 2(m+1)\:|\:(2m+1)\pm\sqrt{12m^2+12m+1}$

  $\Rightarrow 2(2m+2)+1\pm\sqrt{12(2m+2)^2+12(2m+2)+1}=0$
- $x_1=2(2m+2)+1+\sqrt{12(2m+2)^2+12(2m+2)+1}=0$

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{12(2m+2)^2+12(2m+2)+1}=-4m-5$

$\Rightarrow 12(2m+2)^2+12(2m+2)+1=(-4m-5)^2$

$\Rightarrow 12(4m^2+8m+4)+24m+25=16m^2-40m+25$

$\Rightarrow 48m^2+96m+48+24m+25=16m^2-40m+25$

$\Rightarrow 32m^2+160m+48=0$|:16

$\Rightarrow 2m^2+10m+3=0$ but $\sqrt{\Delta}\notin\mathbb{N}$

Now we have to verify for $x_2$ like above:

- $x_2=48m^2+96m+48+24m+25=16m^2+40m+25$

$\Rightarrow 32m^2+80m+48=0|:16$

$\Rightarrow 2m^2+5m+3=0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{\Delta}=1$

$\Rightarrow m_1=-1\in\mathbb{Z}, m_2\notin\mathbb{Z}$

> But as the author says $m\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{-1\right\}$

Comment: A necessary condition is that $12m^2+12m+1$ is a square number, e.g., take $m=0$, then $x=0,1$ are both integral.

Comment: I'll put all my steps

Comment: Try to express $m$ ($m=-\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-2x-2}$) and find such integers $m$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: You wish to find integer $x$ and $m$ is integer; it's called *diophantine equation*. It's not about calculus or algebra (but my idea of solution was “$m\to-1$ when $x\to\infty$”, ha-ha). I solved it for $m$, and Bernard solved it for $x$. Two ideas! Yeah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I find as the only answers $m=0$ or $m=-2$ or $m=-1$ (though in the latter case there are not two solutions).

To see this, note that if $m=-1$, it' not a quadratic equation, and the  solution is $x=-2$.

If $m\neq -1$, let $x_1, x_2$ be the roots; use Vieta's relations:
$$x_1x_2=-\frac{2m}{m+1},\quad x_1+x_2=\frac{2m+1}{m+1}.$$
If $m, x_1,x_2$ are integers, this implies $m+1$ divides both $2m$ and $2m+1$, hence it divides $1$, whence $m+1=\pm 1\iff m=0,-2$.

For $m=0$, the equation is $\;x^2-x=0$, which has roots $0,1$.

For $m=-2$, the equation is $\;-x^2+3x+4=0$, which has roots $-1,4$.

Comment: If $m=-2$, $x=-1$ or $x=4$. You checked $m=2$, not $m=-2$ in last paragraph. But for $m=-2$ equation is $-x^2+3x+4=0$. Anyway, it was a typo in youe text ;)

Comment: Oops! I miscalculated one coefficient. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's express $x$:
$$
-m = \frac{x^2-x}{x^2-2x-2}.
$$
So,
$$
-m - 1 = \frac{x+2}{x^2-2x-2}.
$$
Denominator never equal to $0$ for integers $x$. If $|x+2|<|x^2-2x-2|$, $m$ cannot be integer (unless $x=-2$; we'll check this case later). Solve this inequality:
$$
|x+2|<|x^2-2x-2|\Leftrightarrow (x^2-2x-2)^2 - (x+2)^2 > 0 \Leftrightarrow x^4 - 4x^3 + 4x - x^2 > 0
$$
But
$$
x^4 - 4x^3 + 4x - x^2 = x(x-1)(x+1)(x-4).
$$
Hence, if $x>4$ or $x<-1$, $m$ cannot be integer. Now we just should check integers $-2\le x\le 4$ (don't forget about $x=-2$).

- $x=-2$, $m=-1$
- $x=-1$, $m=-2$
- $x=0$, $m=0$
- $x=1$, $m=0$
- $x=2$, $m=1$
- $x=3$, $m=-6$
- $x=4$, $m=-2$

Excluding $m=-1$, possible $m$ are
$$
-6, -2, 0, 1.
$$
But *both* roots must be integers; so, $\boxed{m=-2}$ or $\boxed{m=0}$.

Comment: Michael as I said above, I don't understand how did you arrive at $m=\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-2x-2}$

Comment: @Lucas, your equation is linear w.r.t. $m$

Comment: @Lucas: He is stating something true for $m$ and any one root $x$. It is just by algebraic rearrangement.

Comment: @Lucas, could you subtract $1$ from a fraction?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza how did you come to the conclusion that $-m-1=...$ ?

Comment: @Lucas, I completely misunderstood you. Do you familiar with algebra?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I suppose that you get from $m\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{-1\right\}$